# How can i rip a circle open and turn it into a straight line?

Tags: animation, mathematics, 2d

I'm learning Blender so i can use it to do math animation videos, I've been trying to turn a circle into a line so i can measure the circumstance for a long time, and it didn't work sadly :(

Comment: Can you please be more specific on what you want to accomplish?

Comment: i think this addon will help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XMimQfQR_ss

Comment: @Ben 
I wanna do something similar to that  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YokKp3pwVFc

Comment: @BoudMath please add some screenshots and/or short animation of what you want to achieve. This video is nearly 3 minutes long with different animation schemes going on there. We can't guess which one you want.

Comment: In 1:52 he ripped the circle and turned it into a straight line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to animate the **Bevel Factor** of a bezier curve that consists of the circle and the flattened line extending at one end.

You start with a bezier circle and turn off *Cyclic* in the properties panel.

[image: cyclic off]

In edit mode, rotate the handles by 45 degrees so that the circle shape is restored. One end of the arc is extruded to the bottom (with its handles rotated horizontally), the other end gets extruded along a line with the length of the circle's circumfence.

[image: rotated]

[image: extruded]

Add another curve – either a NURBS or bezier – to act as a *Bevel Object*. In the example I used a NURBS path with 0.05 length. In the properties of the “circle” select the new curve as bevel object and set the bevel factor mapping to *Spline*

[image: bevel settings]

Add a driver to both *Start* and *End* of the bevel factor by right clicking on it and selecting *Add Driver* > *Manually Create Later (Single)*

In the F-Curve editor (Graph Editor panel > *Drivers* mode > *Drivers* tab) set the drivers variable to the *X Location* of the circle.

[image: drivers panel]

The scripted expression for the *Start* should be `var / (2*pi) / 2` (as the driver should run from $0$ to $0.5$ as the circle moves from $0$ to $2\pi$. The *End* expression is `var / (2*pi) / 2 + .5` (running from $0.5$ to $1$).

Finally, you can animate the X location of the circle.

[image: result]

Another approach could be to animate the control points individually. If you go that route, you might want to look into an addon called *Animation Nodes*. A similar animation using a 3D rope unwinding has been explained in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/116631/34236) by *Omar Ahmad*.

Comment: i have followed you literally, when i reached the last step everything just disappeared :(

Comment: Could you please describe, what you mean by “everything”? Did the object disappear (in which case you maybe forgot to add the `+0.5` to the *End* factor or assigned the expressions the other way around, i.e. end being smaller than start) or do you have problems accessing the 3D view again after switching to the Graph Editor?