# Deform Helix Around Spline in Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

I know in this answer it has been shown how to create a helix in animation nodes: [How to make a rope winding animation?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116608/how-to-make-a-rope-winding-animation/116631#116631)
However, I'm wondering if there is anyway make a helix deform to the curves of a spline, achieving a similar result to the below image where I applied curve modifier to a helix curve.

[image]

Comment: Just add a curve modifier to the target object from the answer you have indicated in your question. You can also find this related answer useful https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76756/how-to-animate-winding-a-ribbon-onto-a-cylinder/76788#76788

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is change the basis of the parametric equation to the tangent, normal, and cotangent of the spline. The cotangent is computed by crossing the normal and the tangent vectors.

[image: Node Tree]

Note that the samples vectors are not normalized.