# Out of ideas - Is there a way to roll a string on a spool?

Tags: physics

I can't find any answers or solutions that match what I need.

Think of a roll of toilet paper - and as it's rolling, the spool fills up. I need that, but it needs to be string, so it would fill left to right, and look organic, with the string rolling from the bottom.

Are there ANY ways to do this?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116608/how-to-make-a-rope-winding-animation

There was another question like this before, hopefully this helps

Comment: Yeah but I don't want to show the string flying around. Thanks.

Comment: here I gave an answer that may inspre you but it was not made with physics: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183182/animating-wire-cable-rope-wrapping-around-a-cylinder   here a tutorial for physics (in french but wit subtitles) but I think it's same as Alex method: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-S2_Mrkh6eU

Answer (score 1):

I will warn you. If you are attempting to make a very long string and have it be a self colliding object, you will need a very strong computer. I would start with a "noodle." By this I mean just one curve straight curve and then slowly add more and more vertices.

To start setting up your scene just add a plane and scale it up 10. This is just a preference for the size, but you should have something that it can fall on. Next, you will need the "spool" but you could easily just use a cylinder to test how your computer runs it. Next is adding your actual string. Add a curve path and put it above so that it can fall on your cylinder. I would subdivide this curve at least twice.

Make the plane and cylinder to collision in the physics body editor. Set the curve to "soft body" and uncheck "Goal." You might want to increase the thickness of the curve, go to the  "Object data properties" panel and under the geometry tab, increase the bevel depth to something like".01" or ".02". You can play around and see what you like

If all of this has worked for you so far, you can start to increase the complexity of your scene and the complexity of your path. Subdivide stretch and shape your string. And that should be enough to get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Wow thank you so much. I will try this method. I was going to do a screw array and just have a invisible box move from left to right unveiling each new 'loop' on the spool. I will try this and report back.

Comment: Yes - the string was just too much for my computer to handle. The unveiling of each circle of new string was rejected since they want it to be more realistic. Is there a way to do this other than the suggestions?

Comment: @artmajor1 does it need to be colored? Give us more information on what you want the end product to be like and I can see if I (or anyone else) can give you a better-personalized answer

Comment: I'm in a nightmare stage right now. It won't even animate correctly. The fluid motion just falls through the cylinder instead of wrapping around it. The animation plays back fine watching it regularly, but as soon as I press render animation it goes haywire.

Comment: Could you show me what you mean? It falls straight through? Keep in mind that the vertex collision is how the simulations work. If you have too many the animation will slow down, If you have too little it won't collide. What do you mean by "it goes haywire?" Does it glitch out?

Comment: Could I possibly send you the file?

Comment: You could post it here. Upload it using some permanent link. Like Mega .nz

Comment: Ok great I will do that and let you know when. Thank you.